# Difference between gatsby-theme-material-ui and gatsby-plugin-material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, gatsby

I am designing a web page with gatsby and I would like to use material UI, but I don't know which plugin to use.

My questions are :

- Is there a difference between those two, and how can I implement them in order to have a Theme Customized ?
- Where should I put the `theme.js` and where to put the `ThemeProvider` wrapper ?
- How to configure the project ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both packages do the trick: Get Material UI into your project.

The difference is that `gatsby-theme-material-ui` is more complete and user-friendly for beginners.  For example with the `plugin`, you have to make sure you load the roboto font or the MUI `theme` yourself. The `theme` sets everything you need for Material UI up for you and you can start developing right away.

All the `plugin` does is to make sure the Material UI styles are properly loaded into your project. This is important because of how Gatsby works with server-side rendering. This can be tricky to get right and understand when starting out. But you still have to get your fonts and the theme provider setup as explained in the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-material-ui/#theme-vs-plugin).

There is a technical [comparison](http://Theme%20vs.%20Plugin%20%20%20%20%20%20gatsby-plugin-material-ui%20solves%20FOUC,%20auto%20prefixing%20and%20minification.%20%20%20%20%20gatsby-theme-material-ui%20uses%20the%20plugin%20under%20the%20hood,%20adds%20web%20fonts,%20meta-viewport,%20CSS%20baseline%20and%20mui%20theme%20support%20and%20has%20material%20ui%20styled%20gatsby%20link%20components) what each plugin does:

> Theme vs. Plugin
>
> - gatsby-plugin-material-ui solves FOUC, auto prefixing and minification.
> - gatsby-theme-material-ui uses the plugin under the hood, adds web fonts, meta-viewport, CSS baseline and mui theme support and has material ui styled gatsby link components

#### For new users I would recommend `gatsby-theme-material-ui`

> how can I implement them in order to have a Theme Customized

Follow the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-theme-material-ui/#theming). Create the file `src/gatsby-theme-material-ui-top-layout/theme.js` and use this file to customize your theme as described in the [MUI docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/).

> Where should I put the theme.js and where to put the ThemeProvider wrapper

Follow the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-theme-material-ui/#customizing). Create a provider in `src/gatsby-theme-material-ui-top-layout/components/top-layout.js`.

> And also how to configure the project

Follow the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-theme-material-ui/#install).

```
// with npm
npm install gatsby-theme-material-ui @material-ui/core

// with yarn
yarn add gatsby-theme-material-ui @material-ui/core
```

Edit gatsby-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    // ... other plugins
    `gatsby-theme-material-ui`
  ],
};
```

Your Gatsby configuration is done.

Comment: Thank you so much @EliteRaceElephant that was really helpful!!!!!!, by the way I am new at making questions here, sorry if I make a mistake.                                                         
A good example of how to sort the folders and files can be found in this repo [link](https://github.com/hupe1980/gatsby-theme-material-ui/tree/master/examples/simple). In case you are having problems make sure your project looks exactly like this one